# Getting error when trying to export Python file that have OpenCV into exe

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, opencv, python

I am getting error when trying to convert the python file (main.py) into exe file that contain OpenCV module using PyInstaller. The program can run when using PyCharm. This is the error I get when I open the main.exe

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I tried to use hidden import but none of that working

Comment: can you please add the rest of the code for more context.